# Print message if dates in file are the same

Tags: python, file, datetime

My code right now.

```
start = datetime.strptime(startDate, "%d/%m/%Y")
end   = datetime.strptime(endDate,"%d/%m/%Y")

with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    alldata = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "|")

    for line in alldata:
        alldataLine = datetime.strptime(line[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
        if alldataLine >= start and alldataLine <= end :
            print("{0} --> {1}".format(line[0], line[1]))
```

my file:

```
30/12/2015|3990.0
30/12/2015|6190.0
31/12/2015|12304.0
02/01/2016|12054.0
02/01/2016|8720.0
02/01/2016|18104.0
```

What i want is if i have same date i want to my program print something after last same date.

example:

```
30/12/2015 - 31/12/2015

30/12/2015 --> 3990.0
30/12/2015 --> 6190.0
"one date"

31/12/2015 -->12304.0
"one date"
```

I tried to compare line[0] with line [0] but it will print "one date" after every date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and check the lines before and after:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    alldata = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(alldata):
        alldataLine = datetime.strptime(line.split('|')[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
        if alldataLine >= start and alldataLine <= end :
            print("{0} --> {1}".format(line.split('|')[0], line.split('|')[1]))
        try:
            if line.split('|')[0] == alldata[i - 1].split('|')[0] and line.split('|')[0] != alldata[i + 1].split('|')[0]:
                print("one date")
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Comment: @BullzY what about testing it? :)

Comment: TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable, it pop up on try and catch line

Comment: I tried without try and catch and also no error , nothing

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I tried and again list object has no attribute split, but i join alldata too and now i have this error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: @BullzY This is what writing code means, not being afraid of trial and error, look at the answer for a fix to that error.

Comment: @BullzY lol I had not noticed that you use a csv reader and not raw file access

Comment: it half working, sleep time included and i don't know

Comment: @BullzY Try now, this is a completely different version

Comment: could you write it from beggining im receving some unexepted value error? :)

Comment: ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: i doesn't exepted him :D

Comment: @BullzY I fixed it too, tell me any other errors, this delayed debugging session is so much fun :D

Comment: Not for me , trying to fix this for  3 and half hour

Comment: @BullzY Life is hard, and programming is no exception, what is the error now?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range
i tried try and catch for this error and my table is empty

Comment: @BullzY at which line?

Comment: if line.split('|')[0] == alldata[i - 1].split('|')[0] and line.split('|')[0] != alldata[i + 1].split('|')[0]:

Comment: @BullzY wait a second your file is 891 lines long? Why don't you split it into multiple files?

Comment: @BullzY fixed again, adding a focused try catch tell me any problems

Comment: I tried without new code and my table is empty, maybe i have problem with line 5 (printing table)

Comment: I will split it, i'm on 85 % of my project, this now is hardest part

Comment: Thanks , finnaly it works, i think i wasted time but i will figure out what i need to do. I should write it on the beginning...

Comment: What i need to do is if i have same date i must print one and make sum of my prices in that date :)